# Problems with Serialization

Tags: android, serialization

i'm having a few problems with serializing my objects.

I think that i'm missing something, because my application doesn't save the .dat like should be.

Let's show some code :

**Load .dat file**

```
public void gravar(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
      out.writeObject(lista);
      out.writeObject(cadeiras);
      out.writeObject(notas);
      out.close();
  }
```

**Save .dat file**

```
public void carregar(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
     lista=(ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
     cadeiras=(ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
     notas= (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
      in.close();
  }
```

When i try to save the file, my application catch the exception **FileNotFoundException** here :

```
case R.id.gravar:
        ObjectOutputStream out;

           try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fich));
                gravar(out);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nice!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return true;
```

**fich** is this :

```
private static String fich = "gravar.dat";
```

what i'm missing? For better help, i let my code here.

http://pastebin.com/Ax2cHjUA

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is, instead of

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fich));
```

paste this

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.openFileOutput(fich, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY));
```

the same for output.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the whole path instead of only the filename to `FileOutputStream`.

If that doing that does not work try

```
new FileOutputStream(new File(fich));
```

Comment: I know the answer, i will post the answer when i can (+/- 7hours).